# Animate an array of buttons in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, arrays, loops, xamarin, button

I have many buttons in my MainActivity.xml and i wanted to add an animation to all of them such that when the MainActivity is launched all buttons get a TRANSLATIONX animation to bring them into view. I have succesfully created the Button array using button as a data type and added three buttons to it as a sample...
The problem however is iterating through the button array to add animation property to each...
Here is the trier code i used to reach where i am, Suggestions and Solutions are greatly appreciated...

```
 class Prime : AppCompatActivity
    {
     //Creating button array
      Button[] mybuttons;
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Prime);
         //Button definitions
     Button button1 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
     Button button2 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
     Button button3 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);

       //Adding the  buttons to an array
            mybuttons = new Button[3] { button1, button2, button3 };
      //Defining a view animation
   ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(button3, "translationX", 130f);
            animator.SetDuration(2000);
            animator.Start();
   //This is where i need the loop code to iterate through the button array and to each of them them the animation object property
```

I tried replacing the `button3` parameter in the `ObjectAnimator.OfFloat` method with `mybuttons` but it didnt work. Thanks

Comment: you can iterate an array with `foreach` or `for` - is that what you need?

Comment: Yes Jason, i used ```foreach(Button button in mybuttons){}```. Thanks for the suggestion bro

Comment: If you've solve the issue, please post an answer and accept it. It'll help others who face the similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `foreach` works fine to access every button in the array and style it with respect to the Object Animator.

```
    foreach(Button button in mybuttons){
      ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(button, "translationX", 130f);
           animator.SetDuration(2000);
           animator.Start();
}
```

The foreach loop is easy to understand and implement for Button arrays than its counter parts